# Strip out C-style comments from a []byte

Tags: regex, go

all. I'm trying to write a wrapper for a particular type of config file, which is JSON encoded. Unfortunately, this file contains C-style comments, (`//` and `/* */`,) and these cause errors in `json.Unmarshal`. Is there a way force Unmarshal to ignore these comments, or otherwise remove them easily?

I'm looking into `regexp` now, but I'm hoping there's an elegant solution that I, as a beginner in Go, might not be able to come up with in the course of a few minutes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'll have to strip out the comments, as the JSON specification does not allow comments. A regular expression can do the job.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)

var bytes = []byte(`// this is a line comment
this is outside the comments
/* this
   is
   a
   multi-line
   comment */`)

func main() {
    re := regexp.MustCompile("(?s)//.*?\n|/\\*.*?\\*/")
    newBytes := re.ReplaceAll(bytes, nil)
    fmt.Println(string(newBytes))
}
```

Comment: This did the job perfectly. Thank you very much!

Comment: @jnml You're right (although I might grumble about the lack of a newline at the end of the string). I'll leave that as an exercise to the asker if he/she's interested.

Comment: Note that this will fail if you have // in a string.  I've been trying to figure a good regex way to detect being inside a string but haven't come up with one that's bulletproof.

Comment: I don't believe there's any 100% correct way to do it with only a regular expression. But if I'm wrong, I'm interested in the solution.

Comment: A regular expression will *absolutely not* do the job. You might be able to come up with some regex patterns that work *most of the time*, but for any regex, there will be an infinite number of potential input cases where the regex will mishandle and you will end up with corrupted data. The proper way to do this would be to create a lexer that will read JSON tokens and ignore comments. A quick search didn't turn one up (for me) in native Go, but as an example, a C version can be found at https://github.com/liquidaty/json_uncomment

Answer (score -1):

You'll most certainly need to write something up as JSON doesn't allow for comments, so likewise I'd be surprised if the go json pkg facilitated ignoring comments that aren't part of the spec.